# What animal this bone belongs to?

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology, bone

I recently found this bone on the balcony of my house.
[image]
In case it helps, my house is in the northwest of Spain next to a park in a coastal city, and size is 15-20 mm.

Does anyone know what animal it could belong to and what part of it it is?

Comment: Could you please edit in the size of the bone  - it looks like it is very small, given that you appear to have it on the palm of your hand.  Size gives us important clues about what sort of animal we might be looking at.

Comment: Seems shaped like a fish jaw, are you anywhere near the ocean/sea?

Comment: Edit my question adding more info, thanks comments. There are seagulls in the park, it is possible that they bring things from the sea.